# Another "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier"

Tags: javascript, syntax-error, production-environment

Please, I'm having trouble with sntax and I don't know why.
My script is

```
var popup = document.getElementById("mypopup");
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close-btn")[0];
var sticker = document.getElementsByClassName("sticker")[0];

window.onload = function() {
  popup.style.display = "inline-block";
  sticker.style.display = "none";
}

span.onclick = function() {
  popup.style.display = "none";
  sticker.style.display = "inline-block";
}

window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == popup) {
    popup.style.display = "none";
    sticker.style.display = "block";
  }
}
```

and it seems the error is in the line

```
span.onclick = function() {
```

The console message is just "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier" and just appears on production environment.

Hope you can save me!

Comment: There is no syntax error in that code.

Comment: please add html & css code also..

Comment: FYI, use addEventListener

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the addEventListener
like so
`span.addEventListener("onclick", yourFunction)`
or it doesn't work